# How to troubleshoot undefined field text error?

Tags: solr, solrnet

I have added 5 new cores in development and they work fine. However, when I added them in production they are not loading. Upon checking the logs I see the following message 5 times (once for each of the new cores).

My best guess as to what this means is that in the schema.xml it is using some unrecognized field type. I am only using basic though (boolean, int, double, long, string, and text_general) so I don't see how it could be that.

Can anyone confirm whether it has something to do with this or suggest what next steps I should take to troubleshoot?

```
24-Apr-2018 14:04:51.409 SEVERE [searcherExecutor-4-thread-1] org.apache.solr.common.SolrException.log org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: undefined field text
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.getDynamicFieldType(IndexSchema.java:1064)
    at org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema$SolrQueryAnalyzer.getWrappedAnalyzer(IndexSchema.java:340)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.AnalyzerWrapper.initReader(AnalyzerWrapper.java:81)
    at org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer.tokenStream(Analyzer.java:132)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.newFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:408)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.getFieldQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:958)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.handleBareTokenQuery(SolrQueryParserBase.java:759)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Term(QueryParser.java:300)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Clause(QueryParser.java:186)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.Query(QueryParser.java:108)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.QueryParser.TopLevelQuery(QueryParser.java:97)
    at org.apache.solr.parser.SolrQueryParserBase.parse(SolrQueryParserBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.solr.search.LuceneQParser.parse(LuceneQParserPlugin.java:72)
    at org.apache.solr.search.QParser.getQuery(QParser.java:142)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent.prepare(QueryComponent.java:117)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1797)
    at org.apache.solr.core.QuerySenderListener.newSearcher(QuerySenderListener.java:64)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore$5.call(SolrCore.java:1586)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Usually this is caused by assuming a default search field - usually named `text` - that is configured in `solrconfig.xml` or you have code that doesn't specify the field to search, and there _is no default field defined in `solrconfig.xml`_.

Comment: @MatsLindh I'm not sure what you mean. It sounds like you're talking about an issue in my code, but when I start up the server and go to the Administration portal, I can see the cores aren't loaded and above is the text from the log. So this is before any code of mine... but maybe that's not what you're referring to?

Comment: can you show us your schema.xml ?